# url rewriting in jsp so that .jsp file will give 404 error

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, url-rewriting

If i have page in context called `about.jsp` and if i wants to show that page only with `/about` i will do following thing

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>/about.jsp</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/about.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>/about.jsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/about</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

If a request come to `about.jsp` then that page must not be show, it must now 404 error because i already wrote the rewrite rule for `about.jsp`.

Means in short, request must proceed only when `/about` is in url not the `/about.jsp`

Answer (score 1):

Putting JSPs under /WEB-INF will prohibit it from direct access.